# How to add common functions to template classes?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two template classes, pseudocode:

```
template<class L, class M>
class A
{
  L l; // copyable
  M m; // only moveable
}

template<class L, class M>
class B
{
  L l;
  M& m_ref;

  B(A& a, ExtraParameter ep)
    : l(a.l.subset(ep))
    , m(a.m) {}

  // +copy and move constructors and operators
}
```

(The idea here is to be use `B`'s as references to parts of `A`'s. So l might be different, but `b.m_ref` references an `a.m`.)

Depending on `L` and `M`, I want to add some member functions that are added to both functions. This functions need access to an `L` and an `M`. 
**(how) is this possible?**

*edit: Emphazise the depending on `L` and `M`. There will be different combinations of `L` and `M` and some allow extra member functions and/or are specialised to use features of `L` or `M`.*

I tried to add these to `B` and made `A` a child of `B`. But I failed to come up with an move-operator for `A` that updates `m_ref`.
*edit: I found the move operator by casting `this` to `B`. I still do not like this, but I gone close this question, since the problem is solved.*

I thought about adding the new member function to a third class template `C` and make both (`A` and `B`) children of `C`. But I was not able to think of a way to provide the reference to `M`. CRTP does not seem to fit, since only `L` and `M` should be template parameters of `C`.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning about CRTP. It seems that CRTP can do the job here. Just put `getL`/`getM` functions into `A` and `B`, and CRTP should call these to get `L` and `M`.

Comment: "only `L` and `M` should be template parameters of `C`" Why? `C<A<L, M>>` can have access to `l` and `m`

Comment: @Caleth I will need to specialise `C` for different combinations of `L` and `M`. I would like to be sure, that `A` and `B` call the same logic, have the same functions from `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you misunderstand what you can do with CRTP. The template base can have `L` and `M` as parameters

```
// base template
template <class AorB, class L, class M>
class C
{
};

// partial specialisation for some pair of L, M
template <class AorB>
class C<AorB, int, std::string>
{
};

template<class L, class M>
class A : public C<A, L, M>
{
  L l; // copyable
  M m; // only moveable
}

template<class L, class M>
class B : public C<B, L, M>
{
  L l;
  M& m;

  B(A& a, ExtraParameter ep)
    : l(a.l.subset(ep))
    , m(a.m) {}
}
```